# Attachments: undefined Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics

I am trying to pull an attachment from an email which is a zip file and send that file to Google Analytics to upload the data. I am struggling with the getAttachment part in the script as it is showing as undefined. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have now fixed where it is pulling the right attachment by using: `var attachments = messages[0].getAttachments();` However I am now getting a new error where it seems to be looking for a title of the attachment but it is still showing as undefined.

```
        function refundImport() {

/// use custom report to schedule the email - will need to adjust the processCsv() function based on your schema
/// if you are using a non-bing data source - you will probably need to adjust the findCsvAttachments() function as it grabs a zip file now

var CONFIG = {
    'emailSubject': 'Refunded or Partially Refunded Orders - TKS',
    'customDataSourceId': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'now': new Date(),
    'zipFileName': 'refunded_or_partially_refunded_orders.zip',
    //'csvFileName': 'refunded_or_partially_refunded_orders.csv',
    'analyticsAccountId': '12345678',
    'analyticsPropertyId': 'UA-12345678-1'
}
//adds one whole day to a date object - can take negative days if you want yesterday etc

function addDaysToDate(DATE, DAYS) {
    var newDate = DATE.getTime() + DAYS * 3600000 * 24;
    var newDate1 = new Date(newDate);
    return newDate1;
}

//takes a date object and formats it as a string

function formatDateAsString(DATE) {
    var dateString = Utilities.formatDate(DATE, 'GMT+12:00', 'yyyy/MM/dd');
    return dateString;
}

//after and before must be date strings - use the above function

  function grabEmailAttachments(SUBJECT, AFTER, BEFORE) {
var query = 'subject:' + SUBJECT + ' ' + 'has:attachment after:' + AFTER + ' ' + 'before:' + BEFORE;
//assumes only 1 will match - if more than 1 - will match the first one
var thread = GmailApp.search('in:inbox from:"noreply@highviewapps.com"');
var messages = thread[0].getMessages();
var content = messages[0].getPlainBody();
//var attachments = thread.getAttachments()[0];
var attachments = messages[0].getAttachments();
//thread.moveToTrash();
return attachments;
}

  // finds csv attachment and creates 2d array of row,column e.g. csv[0][1] = value in row 0 column 1 of csv

  function findCsvAttachment(attachments, zipFileToSearch, fileNameToSearch) {

    var counter = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < attachments.length; i++) {

        if (attachments[i].getName().search(zipFileToSearch) != -1) {

            var unzip = Utilities.unzip(attachments[i]);

            var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(unzip[0].getDataAsString(), ",");

            counter = counter + 1;
        }
    }

    if (counter == 0) {
        Logger.log('No file with ' + fileNameToSearch + ' in its name was found.');
    }
    if (counter == 1) {
        return csvData;
    }
    if (counter > 1) {
        Logger.log('More than 1 file with ' + fileNameToSearch + ' in its name was found - the last one was used.');
    }

}

function processCsv(csvData, date) {

    var headers = 'ga:transactionId,ga:productSku,ga:productPrice,ga:quantityRefunded,ga:transactionRevenue';
    var dataForUpload = headers;
    return dataForUpload;
}

//assumes media dataType for upload https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/uploads/uploadData

function uploadDataToAnalytics(data, accountId, webPropertyId, customDataSourceId) {

    var dataBlob = Utilities.newBlob(data, "application/octet-stream");

    var upload = Analytics.Management.Uploads.uploadData(accountId, webPropertyId, customDataSourceId, dataBlob);

    return upload;

}

///////// ACTUAL IMPLEMENTATION OF SCRIPT /////////////

var tomorrowString = formatDateAsString(addDaysToDate(CONFIG.now, 1));

var yesterdayString = formatDateAsString(addDaysToDate(CONFIG.now, -1));

var todayString = formatDateAsString(CONFIG.now);

var emailAttachments = grabEmailAttachments(CONFIG.emailSubject, yesterdayString, tomorrowString);

var csv = findCsvAttachment(emailAttachments, CONFIG.zipFileName, CONFIG.csvFileName);

var csvForUpload = processCsv(csv, yesterdayString);

var analyticsUpload = uploadDataToAnalytics(csvForUpload, CONFIG.analyticsAccountId, CONFIG.analyticsPropertyId, CONFIG.customDataSourceId);
```

}

[image: Picture showing undefined]

[image]

Comment: Avoid asking follow up questions. Please post questions separately instead of combining your questions into one. Doing so ensures that your question is answered fully and that people with similar problems in the future will be able to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing these lines of code

From:

```
var attachments = messages.getAttachments();
```

and

```
var unzip = Utilities.unzip(attachments[i]);
```

To:

```
var attachments = messages[0].getAttachments();
```

and

```
var unzip = Utilities.unzip(attachments[i].copyBlob());
```

Comment: That seemed to work as it moved me to my next step. I am now getting a new error which I think may be related. Going to edit the comment with the full script.

Comment: Added the picture as well to show what the error is. Looks like it is coming from line 54 and the fileNameToSearch variable is showing as undefined along with the unzip and csvData variable. Is this because the attachment is showing as an array and it is not picking up the right one?

Comment: Made the changes and still getting the same error for line 54 even with the copyBlob part added